# SQL Server trigger: How to know when parent table record is deleting

Tags: sql-server, triggers

I have a product table with a dependent photo table that keeps products to be advertised for each week, e.g., 52 sets of products a year. I have a separate area for product and photo library records, which update/insert using triggers keeping the library up to date from the last product / image save.

Insert/update work well.

I want to delete library images when product images are deleted, but only if it's not because of a product cascading delete (if they remove the product, I still want to keep the product in the library. Also if they remove an individual photo, I want to remove that individual photo from the library)

How would I know in the photo table trigger that the delete is the result of a cascade or not? I've tried checking for a missing product record after the insert/update/delete, but those records still exist as far as the trigger is concerned.

```
create table product (
    id int not null -- primary key
)

create table productimage (
    id int not null -- primary key
    , parentid int not null -- foreign key to product id
)

alter trigger dbo.UpdateProductImageLibrary
on dbo.productimage 
after update, insert as
begin
    declare @insertedcount int, @deletedcount int
    select @deletedCount = count(*) from deleted
    select @insertedCount = count(*) from inserted

    declare @isInsert bit, @isUpdate bit, @isDelete bit

    if( @deletedCount = 0 and @insertedCount > 0)
    begin
        set @isInsert = 1; set @isUpdate = 0; set @isDelete = 0
    end
    if( @deletedCount > 0 and @insertedCount = 0)
    begin
        set @isInsert = 0; set @isUpdate = 0; set @isDelete = 1
    end
    if( @deletedCount > 0 and @insertedCount > 0)
    begin
        set @isInsert = 0; set @isUpdate = 1; set @isDelete = 0
    end

    -- At this point we know if product image is an insert, update or delete
    -- but the parent table's records are still there if we 
    -- check for them, even during a cascading delete
end
```

Comment: I would suggest that is is not usually  a good practice to use cascading deletes espcially if you want specific functionality around them. However, if you havea an FK set up to teh parent table, you cannot remove the product and keep the image, sata integrity rules will not allow (and shoudl not, what doees the parentID mean if you have deleted it in the parent tabel) that.  Perhaps this system would be better off having soft deletes where an inactive flag is set, so that the user can no longer see the produst but it isn't actually deleted.

Comment: Or alternatively, you have your PK FK reversed. It sounds as if theProduct Image table is really the parent if you want to keep it when the product is deleted.. Perhpas the product table shoud contan the FK to the Image table instead.

Comment: @HLGEM I like the soft delete idea. Reversing the FK isn't possible though. The weekly product could be removed entirely which is expected, but the mirroring library product shouldn't be removed. However, if they remove an individual image, it should remove the mirroring library's individual image too. I'd normally handle this in the business intelligence layer outside of the database entirely. We have other apps manipulating products directly in SQL, so we need the integrity constraints. Turning off cascades is a good idea too, but we'll still have the outside app changes that may require it.